# Supported libraries for Quarkus AWS S3

Tags: quarkus

Good evening,

I was redirected to ask my question here instead of Quarkus github.

I would like to check which `AWS S3` library is supported by Quarkus?

Searching through the maven repository: 
https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=quarkus+s3

The closest I could find was the `Camel Quarkus :: AWS S3 :: Runtime` but I believe that's not the right one. Thank you!

Comment: I have used the software.amazon.awssdk (amazon's S3 library) successfully. (not tested in native mode)

Answer (score 2):

I've used the S3 client from Amazon SDK in JVM mode without any problem with this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        <version>${amazon.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it won't work in native mode though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [PR](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/4968), under review at the moment, that introduces AWS S3 extension both JVM & Native.

AWS clients are fully Quarkified, meaning configured via `application.properties` and enabled for dependency injection. In a longer term it will enable other AWS clients too.

Answer (score 0):

[`software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html) works out of the box for Quarkus/JVM application.

Add this to your Dependency Management section of your `pom.xml` file:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.70</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Then add the `S3` dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-nio-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

However in order to work in Native mode you have to register for reflection some filters.
I've created a simple [AWS S3 extension](https://github.com/tpenakov/otaibe-commons-quarkus/tree/master/aws-extension) about it.
Just add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tpenakov.otaibe-commons-quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>otaibe-commons-quarkus-aws-extension</artifactId>
            <version>00.00.07.01</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then add the [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) repository:

```
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
```